# removing duplicate results from friendship table query

Tags: sql

I have two simple SQL tables defined below:

- friend(id1, id2)
- Person(id, name)

The friend table is like:

```
     Id1        Id2  
      1          2  
      1          3  
      2          3  
      3          4
```

How can i query the database for the pair of names of friends, omitting the duplicate?
(That means if the pair of 'john' and 'david' is in answer, i do not need the 'david' and 'john' pair)

Comment: Why not normalize the data to that `id1` is always smaller than `id2`?

Comment: There don't seem to be any duplicates ... add `(1,2) and (2,1)` perhaps?

Comment: @Mureinik :Good suggestion ,but what can we do if the ids are not integers?

Comment: @ErfanSharafzadeh shouldn't matter - every conceivable datatype you can use for an identifier should probably support the `<`, or at least be convertible to one that does.

Comment: @Mureinik thats correct, thank you. Would you please post it so i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a projection to ensure that the friend pairs are ordered lowest first, which makes the duplicate elimination trivial using `DISTINCT`:

```
WITH OrderedFriends AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID1 ELSE ID2 END AS ID1,
        CASE WHEN ID1 < ID2 THEN ID2 ELSE ID1 END AS ID2
    FROM Friends
)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ID1, ID2
    FROM OrderedFriends ;
```

[SqlFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17266)

Note that the original ordering of the Friend pairs is however lost, if that matters?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p1.name,
       p2.name
FROM Friend AS f1
JOIN Person AS p1 ON p1.id = f1.id1
JOIN Person AS p2 ON f1.id2 = p2.id
WHERE f1.id1 < f1.id2
```

May be this.

Comment: Table friend has no column 'name1' nor 'name2'

Comment: This of course assumes that **both** directions are in `Friend` (or at least `id1 < id2`).  If this isn't the case - if not all pairs are recorded this way - it won't report everybody.  Note that, from the OP's post, I **do** assume that both directions are present.

Answer (score 0):

you can always make a union, then query from that for distinct pairs... something like this:

```
select distinct p1, p2 from
(
select id1 p1, id2 p2 from friend
union
select id2, id1 from friend
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this untested code I am generating a relation where I have all the `id`-pairs of all the friendships, the first `id` being the smaller one, while the second is the bigger one. Using the temporary relation I am joining it to the `Person` table to get the `name`s.

```
select person1.name, person2.name
from
    (select distinct leftid, rightid
     from
         (select id1 as leftid, id2 as rightid 
          from friend
          where leftid <= rightid)
     union
         (select id2 as leftid, id1 as rightid
          from friend
          where leftid > rightid)) temptable
join Person person1 
on temptable.leftid = person1.id
join Person person2
on temptable.rightid = person2.id
```

Comment: `UNION` will kindly do the `DISTINCT` for you (the optimizer _may_ be smart enough to remove it).  I'd be very surprised if somebody is their _own_ friend...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, that's true in the case when we assume that a pair is stored only once in the friend table. If there is no constraint protecting the friend table to hold two rows with the same id1 and id2 values, then we cannot guarantee the uniqueness of the pairs. So, if id1 and id2 do not form a primary key, then there is nothing stopping the op from storing two records having 1 as id1 and 2 as id2. Actually, there is one thing which stops him: He has only these two columns, but I believe the small performance price is not too much in exchange of this kind of safety.